# Calling python script in bash script changes type of a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I have a python script that at one point performs division. When I run the script normally from the command line, it treats the numbers as floats, and performs the correct division.
i.e.

```
a = 2 
b = 5
print(a/b)
>0.4
```

I have also written a bash script that among other things, runs this same python script. When I run this bash script, python treats the numbers as integers, performs integer division, and returns zero. Why does this happen?

i.e.

```
a = 2 
b = 5
print(a/b) 
>0
```

EDIT:

python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
a = 2 
b = 5
print(sys.version)
print(a/b)

>3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
0.4
```

Bash script

```
python stack.py

>2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
0
```

Comment: What is your bash script doing with the return value?

Comment: It looks like your bash script uses python2.x whereas you are executing your python script with 3.x. Could you post (a) the exact calls to the script and (b) the shebang you are using?

Comment: Different verison of python perhaps? The first uses python 3, the second uses python 2. You can test this by putting `import sys; print(sys.version)` at the top of your script. It can be solved by making your bash script run `python3` or putting `from __future__ import division` at the top of your script.

Comment: Using a shebang fixed the issue. Interesting that running python --version gives me 3.5.2 but running a bash script invokes python 2 for some reason

Comment: EDIT: This did not fix the issue. Sys.version gives 3.5.2 when the python script is run from the command line. But 2.7.12 when run in the script.     Even when I put a shebang at the top of the python script.

Comment: Just replace `python stack.py` with `python3 stack.py` in your bash script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a shebang line to the top of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

That will ensure that you get a consistent version of Python when it is run from a shell. Without this it appears `bash` is using Python2 where by default division of integers gives an integer result.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it.

Comment: I may have spoken too soon, the issue actually persists even with the shebang. Do you mean at the top of the python script or the bash script? placing it at the top of the python script doesnt change the behavior, but top of the bash script raises a syntax error

Comment: @CHaworth Running the Python script with `python stack.py` (as the shell script does) overrides the shebang and uses the default version of Python instead of python3. You need to run it with something like `./stack.py` Instead.

Comment: when you say default version, why is it that a bash script has a different default version than the command line? Running python stack.py from the command line, runs python 3, and running python --version outputs python 3.5.2

Comment: Maybe the bash script modified the PATH environment variable, or perhaps you have an alias set up for interactive use only: try `which python` to see if it is running an alias or function.

Comment: Yeah I do have an alias set up because I am on ubuntu, and as I understand it, which python needs to point to python 2 for internal purposes

Comment: By default, aliases only work in interactive shells, not in shell scripts. But really, you shouldn't be overriding the shebang in either situation, so just run the script directly rather than specifying `python` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Python2 performs ***floor division*** on ints, whereas python3 performs float division on ints.

If you are trying to write a script file, say `stack.sh`, to execute your python file, say `file_with_python_code.py` , you may be interested in the following:

Designate one file as your script file. We are calling this `stack.sh`. Here is the entire contents of that file:

```
#!/bin/sh

python3 file_with_python_code.py
```

The shebang line lets us specify which shell we want to use to execute the following line. Then you just type whatever you would normally type on the command line to execute you python program.

In this case: `python3 file_with_python_code.py` .

Then run `chmod 700 stack.sh` to ensure you have permission to execute the script.

Finally, run the script:

`./stack.sh`

Hope that helps. Good luck!

---

Bonus Info: if your python file accepts other files as input, you can use positional parameters inside your script file.

For example, if your `file_with_python_code.py` file took `input.txt` as an argument, like this:

`python3 file_with_python_code.py input.txt`

You could change your script file to include the position parameter `"$1"`:

`python3 file_with_python_code.py "$1"`

Then run the script as follows:

`./stack.sh <any input file>`

Example: `./stack.sh input.txt`

Comment: Hi @C Haworth If this does not solve your issue, if you can explain more about what you are trying to accomplish, I'd be happy to help. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 has `float()` so if you would like float division `5/2 = 2.5` then make your code `print(float(a)/float(b))` or `print(float(a/b))`